# augroup end indentation

Tags: vimrc, indentation, autocmd

When I'm editing my vimrc, if I `gg=G` vim autoindents nicely except where `augroup` is involved

I end up with

```
augroup movingBackup
    au!
    au BufWritePost * call WriteBackupFile(expand("%:t"), expand("%:p:h"))
    augroup end

        augroup dotFile
            au!
            au BufWritePost *.dot :silent !start cmd /c "dot -T png %:t > %:r.png"
            augroup end

                nmap j gj
                nmap k gk
```

when I really want

```
augroup movingBackup
    au!
    au BufWritePost * call WriteBackupFile(expand("%:t"), expand("%:p:h"))
augroup end

augroup dotFile
    au!
    au BufWritePost *.dot :silent !start cmd /c "dot -T png %:t > %:r.png"
augroup end

nmap j gj
nmap k gk
```

Comment: can you try using `END` instead of `end` for the closing part of `augroup` ? It should act the same, but with the lower-case version it would not work whereas with the uppercase it works

Comment: @Nobe4 that does it!  (do you want to 'answer' it so I can mark you and the solution?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `END` instead of `end` for the closing `augroup` statement.

Apparently it's a bug (cf Carpetsmoker's comment), it should behave the same but it does not. From the documentation (`:h :aug`):

```
                        *:aug* *:augroup*
:aug[roup] {name}       Define the autocmd group name for the
                        following ":autocmd" commands.  The name "end"
                        or "END" selects the default group.
                        To avoid confusion, the name should be
                        different from existing {event} names, as this
                        most likely will not do what you intended.
```

**Edit:** I opened [an issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/767#issuecomment-212073625) regarding this question on the vim's github repo, and got an answer:

> Although both "end" and "END" work, using "END" is recommended.
>
> I'll change the indent script to also accept "end" (negatively) for
> incrementing the indent.

Comment: This is because the `indent/vim.vim` file does: `elseif prev_text =~ '^\s*aug\%[roup]' && prev_text !~ '^\s*aug\%[roup]\s*!\=\s\+END'`. This is a bug; the check should be case-insensitive.

Comment: Do you know if it's already acknowledged by the vim-team as a bug ?

Comment: No, that's just my own conclusion ;-)

Comment: haha, it's strange that for the indent only the regex is messed up, because for the syntax file, they use `[eE][nN][dD]` each time...  I'll open an issue on the github repo.